# Syntactic sugar for init properties in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
class Person {

   var name: String
   var age: Int

   func init(age: Int, name: String, /** ... **/) {
     self.age = age
     self.name = name
     // ... much typing, much boring.
   }
}
```

I may be a bit lazy but explicitly typing each property out feels a lot like the human compiler at work. Is there any syntax sugar for assigning constructor argument to an instance in Swift?

Comment: Note: I´m just starting out with Swift

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Default Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_319) section of the Swift language book. If you were to make `Person` a struct instead of a class, it would automatically get a *memberwise initializer*:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

let p = Person(name: "Joe", age: 30)
```

Classes or structs that define default values for all their stored properties get a *default initializer*:

```
class Person {
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
}

var p = Person()
p.name = "Joe"
p.age = 30
```

These automatically generated initializers disappear if you declare any of your own initializers in the original type declaration, but you can add other initializers in an extension.